# Creating an Instance of a COM object

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, com

I am modifying an ASP.NET application that uses a COM reference. The code creates an instance of the object the following way:

```
public static object COMCreateObject (string sProgID)
{
    try
    {
        Type oType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(sProgID);
        if (oType != null)
        {
            return Activator.CreateInstance(oType);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(
                 "Could not resolve ProgID for " + sProgID + 
                 " (Ensure the component is registered properly)");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception oExc)
    {
        PageInclude.ermHandleError(
                 "An error occured whilst creating " + sProgID +
                  " - " + oExc.ToString());
        throw oExc;
    }
}
```

The GetTypeFromProgId returns a valid Type of System._COMObject, however three of the properties (DeclaringMethod, GenericParameterAttributes and GenericParameterPosition) are returned with an InvalidOperationException ("Method may only be called on a Type for which Type.IsGenericParameter is true.").

So then calling the Activator.CreateInstance(oType) also fails (Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {508B4562-C89D-4DE9-4523-E6D507B3E3F2} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 800aeb29.)

I'm unsure if the exceptions on the COM component are to blame (it's not a .NET component, so these fields may be missing?).

Any Ideas?

Comment: what specific exception type did `Activator.CreateInstance(oType)` throw?  It can throw quite a few different exception types, so just a single catch-all `Exception` might be counter-productive here.

Comment: Is `800aeb29 (dec 2148199209)` error code meaningful to you in terms of what this particular com class type may emit?  Do the authors of this com component publicize the meanings behind their error codes?  Also, is this com component developed in-house, or is it something we can look up on the net?

Comment: No, I have no indication of the error codes for the component, or the source code. Does this mean you think the issue is with the constructor of the COM class?